# How to parse the swap data of a certain wallet?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, parser

I am trying to parse swap data of a set of wallets:

I tried to do this by using logs of the transactions – they often include data about swaps, however there is no uniform way to parse it, because amount1 and amount0 represent different things, for some reason

**Are there any recommendations on parsing swap data ? (probably, I should just scrape it with selenium from etherscan website ?**

Would be thankful for any tips !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like parsing the swap data directly from the transaction logs won't work since the amount0 and amount1 fields represent different things depending on the transaction.

Scraping the data from Etherscan's website using Selenium is a good idea since they display the swap details in a consistent format.

Etherscan has helpfully provided the information in an easy to read way on their site.

Using Selenium to automatically scrape the data will allow collecting a lot of swap records over time.

Regards,

Ari